# I've used setAttribute to modify the attributes of the <a> tag, but only partially. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

This is my code:

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll ("a");
for (let i = 0; i <links.length; i++) {
    links[i].setAttribute("target", "_self");
}
```

My goal, obviously, is to have all the links open on the current page, but only some of them become **`_self`** and the rest remain **`_blank`**, why?

Comment: Hello and welcome. A snippet reproducing your problem would be great.

Comment: So, does your `links` list contain everything you expect?

Comment: Why are you using `.setAttribute()`? You can directly set the property on the element object: `links[i].target = "_self";`

Comment: What if you use removeAttribute('target')? Links are opening in current tab in default.

Comment: Can you show us your html code please??

Comment: I write the javascript in [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo), and the test page, for example: www.bing.com 
@Maestro

Answer (score 0):

I'm providing you 2 ways to achieve what you want :
First code is what you provided, and the second one is an other way to add `_self` attribute value on links.

```js
let links = document.querySelectorAll ("a");
for (let i = 0; i <links.length; i++) { //1st way
    links[i].setAttribute("target", "_self");
}

links.forEach(link => { //2nd way
    link.target = "_self";  
});
```

```html
<body>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com">Youtube</a>
    <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
    <a href="https://www.twitter.com">Twitter</a>
    <a href="https://www.netflix.com">Netflix</a>
</body>
```

Comment: OP is claiming the the first way does not work. How would your suggestions change that?